# Custom View WIth Part Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

Anyone knows if there is anyway to show the build editor of an espefic part, inside a custom view.

I'm creating profesional, but not in the standard way orchard propose, I have a custom view, but that profesional has a DomicilioPart witch i created, that part has a driver with the overriden method BuildEditor. Is there any way of displaying that especific editor in my custom view?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the method _contentManager.BuildEditor(contentItem) to create the corresponding Edit template.

```
public ActionResult Example(int id) {

    var ci = _contentManager.Get(id);

    var editShape = _contentManaget.BuildEditor(ci);

    // more code
    viewModel.Edit = editShape;

    return View(viewModel);
}

#Template

<div>@Display(Model.EditShape)</div>
```

This [training module](https://orchardtrainingdemo.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Controllers/ContentsAdminController.cs) will teach you about the creation/edit and delete of ContentItems.

Comment: That would tender The editor of al parte attached, and thats not what im  looking forma. Anyway to show only The editor of a particular view

Comment: So, you are interested on the edit shape of a single part not that whole content item?. You could hide the non-wanted parts using the Placement.info. Another possibility is to render the shape directly the shapeFactory.